# My modal dialog crashes (Cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, modal-dialog

My code below crashes if I have the code in `windowWillClose:` that releases
my MyWindowController, otherwise it works fine.

I test it on Mac OS 10.6.8.
I am using XCode 3.1.3.

What have I done wrong?

It seems like the window is not disposed of before I release MyWindowController,
because it crashes in a `NSTableView` method.

My button handler calls `[NSApp stopModalWithCode:0];`

```
MyDialog()
{
    MyWindowController* controller = [[MyWindowController alloc] init];
    [controller showWindow:controller];
    NSWindow* window = [controller window];
    [NSApp runModalForWindow:window];
    [window close];
}
```

In my MyWindowController:

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification*)notification 
{
    [self autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are releasing 'self' in windowWillClose - that seems wrong.

Surely anything like that should be done in dealloc?

```
-(void)dealloc
{
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Also, you might be better autoreleasing controller when it is initially alloc'd?

Comment: I changed the code to this and now it works. I am relatively new with Cocoa programming. I don't know why my table views outlets don't automatically gets disconnected. I needed to manually disconnect my table views datasource from my window controller before I release my window controller. `- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification*)notification 
{
 [tableView setTarget:nil];
 [tableView setDelegate:nil];
 [tableView setDataSource:nil];
 [self autorelease];
}`